# Placeholder doesn't work properly in IE, but works for Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, placeholder

I have a textarea that has placeholder. On load the textarea already has value but if I click on it, the value is cleared and the placeholder value is shown.
Everything works fine on Chrome, The issue exists on IE.

Expected results: keep the value that was when the page was loaded

(If i remove the placeholder then everything works fine. But I need the placeholder to be presented)

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, I try to create a sample code and test the issue with IE 11 browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

Address:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea" placeholder="Describe yourself here...">
</textarea>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "Fifth Avenue, New York City";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

As you can see in the test result, sample code works fine and issue is not producible with IE 11.

**Note:** Place holder is not supported in IE 9 or in older version.

I suggest you to make a test with this sample and check whether it is working properly on your side or not.

If still your issue is persist than please try to provide detailed information with any reproducible code example may help us to understand the issue in better way.